# How to create upgrade version of existing project in Microsoft Dynamic CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

I have create a small plug in and I have released it with version 1.0.0. Now I want to add some advance functionality in it and release again with Version 1.1.0. I am beginner of Microsoft Dynamic CRM. I don't know how to keep existing data.

I have tried by following.

```
1- I have created Managed Plugin and released 1.0.0.
2- Now I have added few new functionalities and released new version 1.1.0.
3- I have removed older version 1.0.0 from CRM Account and added new version 1.1.0.
```

But when user import new version 1.1.0, the old data of version 1.0.0 lost. I want to keep all existing data when user add newer version.

Can anybody suggest me steps or link about how to manage?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "old data of version 1.0.0 is lost"? plugins like the name suggestions are used to enforce/implement business logic, they do not have anything to do with data disappearance. If you mean the older version of the plugin is lost, that is intended by design.

Comment: Is your plugin in a managed solution?

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM i.e if I have modified few product, all the changes about will be lost and I will get fresh entity with new records.

Comment: @jasonscript If I am not wrong, Plugin is always Managed solution. We develop in Unmanaged Solution and when we release, we release Managed Solution.

Comment: You can have plugins in unmanaged solutions too. If you deleted the managed solution this automatically deletes all entities included in the managed solution. Your data is gone. You'd better see if you can restore from a backup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've published your customizations as a **Managed** solution (which, from your comments you have), and you deleted the managed solution from your CRM environment, then any entities included in that solution have been deleted from your CRM environment, including all the data included.

This is by design for managed solutions.

The only way you will get that data back is via backup-recovery if you have backups in place.

---

*Update*

Some additional links from Microsoft about solution versioning:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328109.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309325.aspx

Comment: I got you. If I am not wrong, I must provide Managed packaged to user. Let's say I have given a PlugIn with Version 1.0.0.0 which has some functionality related to Product entity. After 5 month, I add few field in Product entity, modify some field and release it with Version 1.0.1.0. It means whatever user has performed in Product entity in Version 1.0.0.0 will be lost when user will add Version 1.0.1.0. This should not be the Cycle of Development. If it would be the Development cycle, user must create new CRM account for every new version. I am missing something. Please suggest.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the original managed solution. You should be able to import `1.0.1.0` and it will overwrite/replace `1.0.0.0` without deleting data

Comment: 1- If It will overwrite older version, will it keep old data of Product table? 2- If user add 2 different Plugin which customize same entity, what will be the result (i.e `First (Version 1.0.0.0)` plugin add 3 new field in Product entity and `Second (Version 1.0.0.0)` plugin add 2 new field in Product entity, will it keep all 5 field after adding both the plugin?

Comment: (1) My understanding is that managed solution will not delete entities/attributes. So if you delete an attribute in `1.0.0.0` it will still be there in `1.0.1.0`. All data should still be there, as long as you don't delete `1.0.0.0` (2) yes all 5 fields should be present in Product entity

Comment: I got the answer about Version changes with Entities. I have a doubt about Form Design when version changed. I don't know whether I should ask here or not. So I have posted different question for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39405757/how-to-manage-crm-form-field-and-ribbon-button-if-user-add-different-plugin

Comment: Can you please suggest me what happened if Design of same form is different in 2 different Managed solution, both design merge or the latest design will be displayed?

Comment: the form from `1.0.1.0` will replace the form in `1.0.0.0` - i.e. the latest form design will be displayed